# Is there a physical limit to the heights of mountains?

Tags: mountains

I am reading a fantasy novel where there is a mountain range where the average mountain height is 10 miles, so some higher some lower, but all *extremely* high.

This got me wondering if such a mountain range is possible on earth. Mount Everest is just under 5 1/2 miles, so there is no mountains even close to 10 miles here on earth. But I am wondering if that is because it is impossible for that to occur, or if it just hasn't happened but possibly could.

Comment: @Jean-MariePrival Yes I believe it does, sorry that I couldn't find that answer when searching around

Comment: This was discussed in https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9745/how-high-can-a-mountain-possibly-get